# *Playtest feedback request* Puzzle 1

Tags: riddle

I'm working on my first series of puzzles and would love some feedback for any of you that give them a shot.

This first one would be found next to a box with a 4 digit padlock on it. (you can assume it's to help you open the padlock).

Feedback encouraged.

---

[image: Riddle]

**Transcript**

> I'm in a word but never seen
>   Japanese poets of me were keen
>   I'm used a lot to not seem dumb
>   But there's just three left where I'm from

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! I added a transcript of your riddle to the question for the people who are unable to view the image.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for not adding that, I'm still learning the etiquette here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Litterally first time posting, sorry if I mess anything up

Are you a

> Syllable?

I'm in a word but never seen:

> Syllables are only heard, and not read.

Japanese poets of me were keen:

> Haikus are a japanese form of poetry where the amount of syllables per line are fixed

I'm used a lot to not seem dumb:

> Not certain at this point, but people that don't want to seem dumb talk a lot perhaps?

But there's just 3 left from where I'm from:

> 3 syllables in the word syllable

EDIT: Didnt read post enough, looking for a number

Comment: I think you got it. Just count the syllables in each of the $4$ lines.

Comment: For the dumb part: using big words with lots of (answer)?

Comment: Yep you basically got it. I"m going to consider your solution correct as taking your solution plus the comment @Jens added and you have the solution.